# jQuery-file-upload Almond incorrect module build, no module name

Tags: jquery, file, file-upload

I'm trying to integrate the "jquery-file-upload" in a project, but there is the almond in there too.
When I try to open the page and the console, there is this error:

```
9fae76c_almond_2.js:406 Uncaught Error: See almond README: incorrect module build, no module namedefine 
@ 9fae76c_almond_2.js:406(anonymous function) 
@ 36c7495_jquery.fileupload-validate_7.js:18(anonymous function) 
@ 36c7495_jquery.fileupload-validate_7.js:31
step4new:40 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fileupload is not a function(anonymous function) @ step4new:40
```

This is my bower.json of the almond:

```
{
    "name": "almond",
    "license": [
        "MIT"
    ],
    "version": "0.3.2",
    "main": "almond.js",
    "ignore": [
        ".jshintrc",
        "tests",
        "shrinktest.sh"
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to solve or at least bypass this?